# If A is a $C^*$ algebra, then there is a $C^*$ algebra $A_1$ with an identity such that $A_1$ contains A as an ideal.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is in the book **Functional analysis** by John B. Conway. Chapter 9 prop: 1.9.
Basically in the book, he takes $A_1=\{a+\alpha \}$ where $(a+\alpha )$ is just a formal sum. And defined multiplication and addition as:

i) $(a+\alpha )(b+\beta )=(ab+\alpha b+\beta a+\alpha \beta )$

ii) $(a+\alpha )+(b+\beta )=(a+b)+(\alpha +\beta )$

And norm as:$$\|a+\alpha \|=\sup \{ \|ax+\alpha x\|:x\in A,\|x\|\leq 1\}.$$ I am unable to prove that $A_1$ is a Banach algebra. I am trying to show if $\|a+\alpha \|=\|a\|+|\alpha |$ or not but unable to do so.

Comment: The formula $\|a+\alpha\|=\|a\|+|\alpha|$ is wrong. Clearly $A$ is an ideal of $A_1.$ You have to show that $\|a+\alpha\|$ is a norm on $A_1$ and that $A_1$ is a $C^*$-algebra, i.e. $$\|(a+\alpha)^*(a+\alpha)\|=\|a+\alpha\|^2$$ where $(a+\alpha)^*=a^*+\bar{\alpha}.$ The existence of an approximate identity in every $C^*$-algebra is helpful for proving $C^*$ -property of $A_1.$

Comment: Yeah got your point. I have shown everything except to show completeness of $A_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the norm of $a+\alpha$ is **not** $\|a\|+|\alpha|$ in general. That's the norm one uses to make the unitization a Banach algebra, but it is not a C$^*$-norm.

In principle you have that $A_1$ is a $*$-algebra, and you can show that the norm satisfies the C$^*$-identity. Then you can consider its completion $\overline{A_1}$, which ends up being $A_1$ but we still don't know that. Using Hahn-Banach, there exists a bounded linear functional $\varphi$ on $A_1$ such that $\varphi|_A=0$, $\varphi(1)=1$. Now suppose that you have a Cauchy sequence $\{a_n+\alpha_n\}$. We have
$$
|\alpha_n-\alpha_m|=|\varphi(a_n+\alpha_n-(a_m+\alpha_m))|
\leq\|\varphi\|\,\|a_n+\alpha_n-(a_m+\alpha_m)\|,
$$
and it follows that $\{\alpha_n\}$ is Cauchy. From the triangle inequality,
$$
\|a_n-a_m\|\leq\|a_n+\alpha_n-(a_m+\alpha_m)\|+\|\alpha_n-\alpha_m\|
$$
and, since both sequences on the right-hand-side are Cauchy, we get that $\{a_n\}$ is Cauchy.

So $a_n\to a $ in $A$, $\alpha_n\to\alpha$ in $\mathbb C$, and
$$
\|a_n+\alpha-(a+\alpha)\|\leq\|a_n-a\|+|\alpha_n-\alpha|\to0. 
$$

Comment: I am a bit confused about how you use Hahn Banach Theorem to find such a map $\phi$ such that $\phi (A)=0$ and $\phi (1)=1$. If you are taking $\phi$ on $A$ as the zero map and tried to extend it then it will preserve the norm also and norm is zero so the extended $\phi$ will be zero also.

Comment: I got one thing that is the following: Since $A$ is a closed subspace of $A_1$ as $A$ is a Banach space itself and $A_1$ is a metric space so we can use Urysohn's lemma to find a 
such  continuous map $\phi$ and every continuous map is bounded. So we are done. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Urysohn's Lemma has nothing to do with linearity, so it is completely irrelevant here. As for Hahn-Banach, the form you quote is probably the least useful, and not the appropriate one here. See the Corollary to Mazur's Theorem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Geometric_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_(the_Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems)).